# Application is crashing when working with custom model using tflite in flutter. How do i fix it?

Tags: android, flutter, keras, prediction

I have built a custom tflite model which got converted from Keras hdf5 model. But when using the converted model, while making prediction the application is crashing in android, but when I am using the mobile net tflite model which is downloaded from internet works fine with the application. What changes do I have to make? Whether the problem is in the model conversion or in the application?

I have tried using the inbuilt function by tflite package that supports mobile net and various other nets that are given by tflite, I changed to custom build model prediction function and kept the converted file model. In the first case, it worked, but in the second case, it did not.

```
Future prediction(File image) async{
  _recognitions= null;
  var recognitions = await Tflite.runModelOnImage(
  path: image.path,   // required
  imageMean: 0.0,   // defaults to 117.0
  imageStd: 255.0,  // defaults to 1.0
  numResults: 2,    // defaults to 5
  threshold: 0.2,   // defaults to 0.1
  asynch: true      // defaults to true
);
  // var recognitions = await Tflite.detectObjectOnImage(
  //   path: image.path,
  //   model: "SSDMobileNet",
  //   imageMean: 127.5,
  //   threshold: 0.4,
  //   numResultsPerClass: 2,
  //   asynch: true
  // );
  print(recognitions);
  setState(() {
    _recognitions=recognitions;
  });
}
```

I have added 2 models in assets:

```
  assets:
   - images/webdoctor.png
   - assets/detect.tflite
   - assets/labelmap.txt
   - assets/labels.txt
   - assets/modelPneumonia.tflite
```

Expected results would be the working of custom model without app crashing.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and it was a memory leak that crashed the app. I solved it by doing the following:

1. Add the following to close any resource

   ```
   @override
   void dispose() {
     // you can add to close tflite if error is caused by tflite
     // tflite.close();
     controller?.dispose(); // this is to dispose camera controller if you are using live detection
     super.dispose();
   }
   ```
2. Run the Command: `flutter clean`
3. Rebuild your project

P.S. It would be nice if more details on the error from the debug console was given.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping extra lines on labels.txt or labelmap.txt would be an issue. Please make sure you don't keep new lines.

[image: DO:]

[image: Don't:]